# How can I filter data based on a property value?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

Let's say I have the table Survey and the Table Attachment related to it.
Whenever I get the Survey data I use:

```
Survey survey = iSurveyRepository.findOne(id);
```

That is going to get the Survey data and all the Attachments related to it as a list of objects and that's fine, but what I want is to get the Survey data but only the Attachments uploaded by me. (The Attachment entity has an added_by field).

I have heard hibernate has something called filters but I'm not sure how to implement them using annotation based configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are after essentially is Criteria Queries within Hibernate:

[Hibernate Criteria Queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#objecstate-querying-criteria)

Essentially what it means you make queries with Criterion (criteria in plain english) and it calls relevant queries.

e.g.

```
String user = "John";

List surveys = sess.createCriteria(Survey.class)
    .add( Restrictions.like("id", id) )
    .add( Restrictions.like("attachment.added_by", user) )  //where user is a string variable
    .list();
```

This will return all surveys that have attachments created by any user containing text "John".